# Rank in SQL to output the same as Row_Number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to make the Rank and  Dense rank output the same as row_Number

```
select top(100) CVRNummer,VirksomhedNavn 
,row_number() over (order by CVRNummer )  as rknr


, rank() over (order by CVRNummer) as Rankrow

/*
,DENSE_RANK() over (partition by Order by CVRNummer,VirksomhedNavn) as DrankRow
*/



from VirksomhedEllerPerson where CVRNummer is not null
order by CVRNummer,VirksomhedNavn
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data ?

Comment: @Maltbeer . . . This is an extremely odd requirement.  It is like requiring that `sin()` and `cos()` return the same value -- related functions, but they do different things.  Can you explain why?

Comment: I know it is an odd thing to ask, but I just started working with SQL and my manager asked me to do this task, I just have no idea how.

Comment: The task is ment to show that you can make different functions output the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the question, you need to add `Rank() OVER ( ORDER BY cvrnummer,virksomhednavn,newid()) AS rankrow`

This will sort the list as requested

Answer (score 1):

Then just add a unique key to the `order by` as the final key:

```
rank() over (order by CVRNummber, VirksomhedNavn)
```

might work.  In general, you can do:

```
rank() over (order by CVRNummber, <primary key>)
```

(although any unique key will work.)